# Feature that allows finding questions related to your posts that have the same keywords

Tags: feature-request

When I read stackoverflow questions, most of them are out of my capacity.

It would be great to create a menu that would show questions that have the same keywords like the ones that are included in my comments, answers and questions.

Answer (score 1):

there is already something like that

> [image]

you can select the favorite tag and ignore you dont like 
favorite tag question shows with highlight

> [image]

and ignored

[image]

Comment: True, more than that: you can hide questions having ignored tag. (User profile --> "prefs" --> "hide ignored tags")